# Using ActiveRecord to auto populate nested fields. User.Group.New

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

**user.rb**

```
has_many :groups, :through => :group_members, :conditions => ['banned = ?', false]
```

**group.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
```

**Groups controller:**

```
group = current_user.groups.new(:uuid => group_uuid)
```

Rails.logger.info for group.inspect is showing group.user_id as nil ? Why is that... Shouldn't the group.user_id be automatically set when I do a current_user.groups.new() ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're running into is that your associations are inconsistent. In `user.rb`, you have a `has_many :through` relation, which means that an association between a user and a group would be stored in the table `group_members`. In `group.rb`, you have a `belongs_to` association, which means that the association would be stored on a column on `groups` called `user_id`.

You would usually use a `has_many :through` type association when users can belong to multiple groups, and groups can contain multiple users (a many-to-many association). `belongs_to` type associations should be used if a group can only have one user in it, or a user can only belong to one group.

I'm assuming that you want users to belong to multiple groups, and groups to have multiple users. If that's the case, you can fix up your associations by adding the following to `group.rb`

```
has_many :group_members
has_many :users, :through => :group_members
```

Answer (score 0):

**group.rb**

```
belongs_to :owner, :class => 'User', :foreign_key => :user_id
has_many :group_members
has_many :users, :through => :group_members
```

### After create add owner as group member

**user.rb**

```
has_many :own_groups, :class => 'Group',  # own groups
has_many :group_members
has_many :groups, :through => :group_members
```

**group_member.rb**

```
belongs_to :group
belongs_to :user

group = current_user.groups.new(:uuid => group_uuid)
```